# T-Sql: turn multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

How does one turn these multiple rows into one row? N and Y are bool values.

```
Id  IsPnt IsPms, IsPdt  
1   N     Y      N  
1   N     Y      N  
1   Y     N      N
```

into this

```
Id  IsPnt IsPms, IsPdt  
1   Y     Y      N
```

Edit:

The query that produces the resultset looks like this

```
select b.id, 
    CASE mpft.PlanIndCd WHEN 'PBMN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsPnt,
    CASE mpft.PlanIndCd WHEN 'PBMT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsPbt,
    CASE mpft.PlanIndCd WHEN 'PBMS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsPms
from vw_D_SomveViewName pb
   -- bunch of joins 
where mpft.PlanIndCd in ('HANR', 'PBMN','PBMT','PBMS','HAWR')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `MAX()` on this if the values are really `Y` and `N` only.

```
SELECT ID, MAX(IsPnt) IsPnt, MAX(IsPms) IsPms, MAX(IsPdt) IsPdt
FROM   tableName
GROUP  BY ID
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  b.id, 
        MAX(CASE mpft.PlanIndCd WHEN 'PBMN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IsPnt,
        MAX(CASE mpft.PlanIndCd WHEN 'PBMT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IsPbt,
        MAX(CASE mpft.PlanIndCd WHEN 'PBMS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IsPms
FROM    vw_D_SomveViewName pb
        -- bunch of joins 
WHERE   mpft.PlanIndCd in ('HANR', 'PBMN','PBMT','PBMS','HAWR')
GROUP   BY b.ID
```

Comment: You can't use `MIN` or `MAX` if the data type of the columns `IsPnt`, `IdPms` and `IsPdt` are `BIT`s. Well, op updated his question and is showing that those columns aren't actually `BIT`, so, removed the downvote and upvoted it now

Comment: @Lamak i know. but the values illustrated are `Y` and `N`. The OP needs clarification for the data type, if it's BIT then I delete this answer.

Comment: S/he initially said that the `N` and `Y`values were booleans: *N and Y are bool values*. But after that s/he showed that s/he actually is calculating those values as `1` and `0`s from a `CASE` expression, so your answer is perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

Will this work?

```
select
  id,
  max(IsPnt),
  max(IsPms),
  max(IsPdt)
from
  table
GROUP BY
  id
```

Answer (score 0):

After the edit of your question, you can simply use the `PIVOT` table operator directly instead of using the `MAX` expression, something like:

```
SELECT
  Id,
  PBMN AS IsPnt,
  PBMT AS IsPbt,
  PBMS AS IsPms
FROM
(
   SELECT
     id,
     mpft.PlanIndCd, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id
                       ORDER BY ( SELECT 1)) AS RN
   from vw_D_SomveViewName pb
   -- bunch of joins 
   where mpft.PlanIndCd in ('HANR', 'PBMN','PBMT','PBMS','HAWR')
) AS t
PIVOt
(
   MAX(RN)
   FOR PlanIndCd IN ([PBMN], [PBMT], [PBMS])
) AS p;
```

You can see it in action in the following demo example:

[**Demo on SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5cdc1/2)

Answer (score -5):

```
select Id, MAX(IPnt), MAX(IsPms), MAX(IsPdt) 
from table etc
```

Comment: @Mahmoud. Yes. That was implicit in the "etc" bit. I am assuming that the person I am writing to is not an idiot.

Comment: it's not about being "an idiot" or not, it's about submitting a complete answer.  Besides, other users down the road who are less proficient in SQL may find this answer and not understand it.

Comment: Code only answers are bad enough, incomplete (laziness I'm assuming) code only answers are worse